# Commands in a Git Script Functions (Windows) Not Working As Expected in Sub Folder Under a Git Repo

Tags: windows, git, bash, powershell, git-alias

I have the following folder structure...

```
\GitRepo
    \.git
    [files]
    \IgnoredFolder #ignored from .gitignore
        \SubRepo
```

I'm trying to right a script function in my .gitconfig file and I need to know the *current directory*, but I'm getting weird behavior.

For all my tests, I've opened a Console2 window hosting Windows PowerShell to run my git commands.

At the *prompt* if I type **$pwd** it 'correctly' displays C:\GitRepo\IgnoredFolder\SubRepo.  I say 'correctly' but it is in Windows format instead of *Nix.

In my .git config, I've created this alias:

```
test = "!f() { echo ${PWD}; }; f"
```

Now, if I type *git test* from the prompt, I get the 'incorrect' display of /c/GitRepo.  I say 'incorrect' because, ignoring Windows vs *Nix format, I would have expected/liked it to return /c/GitRepo/IgnoredFolder/SubRepo.

Other commands behave same way (i.e. operating in the first folder containing a .git repository instead of the current working directory.

For example, the real alias I want to create basically is a shortcut for init, add, commit, remote, config all in one command.  A pseudo alias would look like this...

```
create = "!f() { git init; git add .; git commit -am "$1"; ... anything else ... }; f"
```

But instead of running on the current directory (the new SubRepo folder I want to 'act on'), it works on the first ancestor folder containing a git repo (c:\GitRepo in this case).

Is there any way to make git alias script functions work on the current directory regardless of whether or not it might be found with in a folder containing a repo or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `git` aliases work from the root of the repository.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17969370/2235132) might help.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt @devnull, but it didn't seem to change the behavior.  I made a test alias like this:  createEcho = "!f() { shift; echo ${PWD}; echo "git init"; }; f, and ran it in my SubRepo directory and PWD is still showing \GitRepo.  Do I have shift in the right place?

Comment: No, it's incorrect.  Look at how the example passes the current working directory as the first parameter.  Moreover, use the first parameter in the function to `cd`, then `shift` and get the remaining arguments.

Comment: Where is documentation on 'shift'?  I was googling for git shift, but doesn't seem to be part of that.  Would like to read up a bit on it.  I *was* hoping to not have to pass in the $PWD to the alias if possible (looking like it isn't), but I'd still like to read up on shift to better understand your answer/syntax.